# How to fix CWE 78: Improper Neutralization of Special Elements used in an OS Command

Tags: c#, security, veracode

anyone knows how to fix CWE 78? Improper Neutralization of Special Elements used in an OS Command ('OS Command Injection')

Here is my code has CWE 78 after veracode scan:
https://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/78.html

```
private void textBox_PreviewMouseDoubleClick(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    SysprepLogViewInfo log = lstView.SelectedItem as SysprepLogViewInfo;

    if (log != null)
    {
        string Logfile = System.IO.Path.Combine(log.Location, log.DisplayName);

        if (System.IO.File.Exists(Logfile))
           Process.Start("notepad.exe", Logfile); // this line was flagged.

    }
}
```

My fix that does not work:

```
private void textBox_PreviewMouseDoubleClick(object sender,System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    SysprepLogViewInfo log = lstView.SelectedItem as SysprepLogViewInfo;
    
    if (log != null)
    {
        string Logfile = System.IO.Path.Combine(log.Location, log.DisplayName);
        var valDesc = new Regex(@"[a-zA-Z0-9\x20]+$");
        if (!valDesc.IsMatch(Logfile))
        {
           System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(string.Format("log file selected is invalid."), "Error");
        }
        else
        {
            if (System.IO.File.Exists(Logfile))
               Process.Start(Logfile);
        }        
    }
}
```

another fix that does not work:

```
private void textBox_PreviewMouseDoubleClick(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    SysprepLogViewInfo log = lstView.SelectedItem as SysprepLogViewInfo;
    if (log != null)
    {
       string Logfile = System.IO.Path.Combine(log.Location, log.DisplayName);

       List<string> logList = new List<string>
       { "C:\\Windows\\Panther\\setupact.log",
         "C:\\Windows\\Panther\\setuperr.log",
         "C:\\Windows\\Panther\\UnattendGC\\setupact.log",
         "C:\\Windows\\Panther\\UnattendGC\\setuperr.log",
         "C:\\Windows\\System32\\sysprep\\Panther\\setupact.log",
         "C:\\Windows\\System32\\sysprep\\Panther\\setuperr.log" };

       if (!logList.Contains(Logfile))
       {
          System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(string.Format("The log file selected is invalid."), "Error");
       }
       else
       {
          if (System.IO.File.Exists(Logfile))
             Process.Start(Logfile);
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've been messing around with this recently and the only way I can clear it is by not passing in the external input, no matter what validations were done on it. Based on a comment in the official veracode forum this is by design and you have no choice but to propose a mitigation and then have to defend that over and over again each time it comes up. Personally I think Veracode can and should do better for example be able to put an attribute on a validation method and only re-flag it as a flaw if that method changes.

Answer (score 0):

I've sometimes had success using something similar to your second fix. But instead of passing the logFile variable to Process.Start, use the string you validated against. Ie, don't just do a contains, but compare each item in the list to your path, if it matches, assign the list item to a new string eg cleanedLogFile, and pass cleanedLogFile to Process.Start.

Have had about 50/50 success clearing the alert.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34983751)